# Linked list program crashes when destroying nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a simple `destructor` method that destroys each node, but I am having some issues. Whenever I attempt to remove an item from my linked list, the element is remove, but then all the following elements are also removed. My program crashes if I attempt to print or add more elements. After it crashes, my text editor highlights my `PrintNode` method.

Here is my `destructor` method:

```
Node::~Node() {
  delete next;
}
```

I am removing elements from my list using this method:

```
Node*Node::DeleteNode(Node *head, string a) {
    if (head == NULL) return head;
    head->next = DeleteNode(head->next, a);
    if (head->get()==a) {
       Node* temp = head->next;
       next = NULL;
       delete head;
       return temp;
     }
    else {
       return head;
    }
}
```

And then I do a simple print:

```
void Node::PrintNode() {
    cout << name << endl;
    if (next) { 
      next->PrintNode();
    }
 }
```

Why is my destructor causing my program to crash?

Comment: Did you debug your code?  Your destructor calls `delete next`, which calls the destructor of `next` which calls `delete next;` which calls the destructor of `next` which calls `delete next;` etc.etc.

Comment: This is a very awkward way of implementing a linked list.  The `Node` class should not have a user-defined destructor at all.  Delete the necessary nodes in your linked list code as needed, and not automatically.  What if you want to remove a single node from the list?  How do your propose to do that with the `Node` class having a destructor like that?

Comment: "What if you want to remove a single node from the list?" That seems like my issue here.

Comment: Well, the simple thing to do is remove the destructor completely from `Node`, and rewrite your function to delete `Nodes` when you need to delete them.  A better approach is to create a linked list class, where the member variable is a pointer to the head node, and then write the requsite functions to add and remove items.  Then the linked list class destructor deletes all the nodes in a loop.  That is the usual way that a linked list class is implemented.

Comment: Is there a recursive way to delete all nodes in linked list class instead of loop?

Comment: Why do you want to introduce recursion?  What if the linked list has 10,000 nodes or 100,000 nodes?  Write a simple loop.

Comment: My opinion? Smart list, stupid node. A node should not know anything about any other node or the list, so it's not in a good position to be making decisions about the list or other nodes. That means no `delete next;` because it shouldn't have the information to make that call.

Answer (score 0):

You just delete the node, not the link towards it.Try this.

```
delete head;
 head=NULL;
```

And remove 
     Delete next;

From destructor,it should remain empty, compiler will automatically call it when you use 
**delete** and delete the node but you should also remove the link towards the node so write

```
head=NULL;
```

after line

```
 delete head;
```

Comment: Try this in DeleteNode function and remains the destructor empty.

Comment: It will work *iff* the `DeleteNode` take a reference to the pointer `DeleteNode(Node*& head)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all it will always have n recursive calls, n assignments here, even if the searching string is in the first node.

```
Node*Node::DeleteNode(Node *head, string a) {
    if (head == NULL) return head;
    head->next = DeleteNode(head->next, a); // n calls, n assignments
    if (head->get()==a) {
       Node* temp = head->next;
       next = NULL;  
       delete head;
       return temp;
     }
    else {
       return head;
    }
}
```

Problem is probably here:

```
Node::~Node() {
  if(next) {
    delete next;
  }
}
```